# SSRS: Showing only columns associated with matrix row group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am attempting to create a report, utilizing a matrix, that only displays columns for associated row groups.

For example, I have a piece of software that allows users of a system to periodically "take samples" which are stored in a database.  This data is stored in such a way that it so grouped by person name.

The format of the report would be like this.

```
Person  Item    TimeStamp1 TimeStamp2 
John    Item1   Value1-1   Value1-2   
John    Item1   Value2-1   Value2-2   
John    Item1   Value3-1   Value3-2   
--PageBreak--
Person  Item    TimeStamp1 TimeStamp2 
Steve   Item1   Value1-1   Value1-2   
Steve   Item1   Value2-1   Value2-2   
Steve   Item1   Value3-1   Value3-2
```

What happens is that I get the line break but the columns for Steve show up in John and John in Steve, like this.

```
Person  Item    TimeStamp1 TimeStamp2 SteveTime1 SteveTime2
John    Item1   Value1-1   Value1-2   
John    Item1   Value2-1   Value2-2   
John    Item1   Value3-1   Value3-2   
--PageBreak--
Person  Item    JohnTime1  JohnTime1 TimeStamp1 TimeStamp2 
Steve   Item1                        Value1-1   Value1-2   
Steve   Item1                        Value2-1   Value2-2   
Steve   Item1                        Value3-1   Value3-2
```

I thought adding a page break based on the user group would work out but extra columns remain.

Is there a way for only columns to display ONLY for an associated group on a page?

Comment: Can you clarify what you'd like to have if John and Steve *are* on the same page?

Comment: I would not like them to be on the same page, ever.  The example is contrived to simplify the scenario.  There are actually several pages of data for John and Steve respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that in your question you mean the first "`TimeStamp1`" is in fact the same as "`JohnTime1`", right?

Don't think you can do this easily in a matrix, if at all. It would probably involve grouping on the ranking of timestamps, and displaying the timestamp for that rank within the row group.

There's a simpler solution though. My suggestion would be to do the following:

- nest the matrix inside a list
- the list will iterate the distinct person/item combinations (or just person, depending on your needs)
- set the `PageBreak` property for the matrix to `Start`
- the matrix has Row Groups on person/item
- the matrix has have Column Groups on the timestamps
- the values (`Value1-1` etc) as data

Answer (score -1):

Couple of ways to do this - personally I would introduce a union to the query, so JohnTime and SteveTime both map to TimeStamp.

There may be times when this is not possible, or prove difficult (increased number of names makes this inpractical), in which case you could put a formula on the column visibility which only displays columns if they have correct name, ie TimeStamp1 and TimeStamp2. I'm not sure if this would slow down the report, if it calculated the contents before turning off visibility.

Anyway, hope this helps!